# How to Add Check Box in Table View Cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am Created custom check box in my table view when i select row that time not changed my check box. Please assist me

## my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

@try {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


            checkButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [checkButton setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 20, 20)];
            [cell addSubview:checkButton];

            pLblCabType = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 5, 200, 20)];
            [cell addSubview:pLblCabType];

            pLblTariff = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 5, 80, 20)];
            [cell addSubview:pLblTariff];

    } 



        [checkButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[pArrImgBullet objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        pLblCabType.text = @"Arul";
        pLblTariff.text = @"Rs.1250";


    return cell;

}
@catch (NSException *exception) {

    NSLog(@"Exception Error is  %@",exception);
}
@finally {

   }
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

@try {




        [checkButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bullet_Select.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [pArrImgBullet replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"Bullet_Select.png"];


    }

}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Exception Error is %@",exception);

}
@finally {

     }
}
```

Thanks in Advance,
S.Arul

Comment: Where are you defining `checkButton` `pLblCabType` `pLblTariff` ? and why you are removing the subviews from the cell view if it's dequeued then assigning values to them ?

Comment: I am creating check button, PLblCabType,PlblTariff into cell suview.

Comment: you have created a subclass of UITableViewCell ?

Comment: Yes, I am created button and added as cell subview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a custom Cell View in a proper way and add your button and other labels to it to it. There is multiple ways to do it. Check this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702) for how to make prototype cells if you are using storyboards (I hope you do), and [this](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/) if you are using xib files.

Answer (score 1):

Try modify below `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method :-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellWithSwitch"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellWithSwitch"] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

return cell;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i need custom bullet type check box in cell left side.